# Getting GPS coordinates from Samsung Intrepid

Tags: windows-mobile, gps

I'm looking into purchasing the new Samsung Intrepid Windows Mobile 6.5 device. Before I plunk down the cash, I'm investigating the available APIs and support resources. I have one question I want answered. It's one question but it's a big one for me. Can I access the GPS coordinates of the device? Does this phone have a location API? I've been searching for code samples (C# or VB.NET) and found nothing. Not even a mention of this capability from a technical / developer perspective. Plenty of sales stuff that mention the phone has GPS but I  need more info. I find that difficult to believe to so I'm willing to accept I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. I don't know the Samsung but WinMob has a special GPS API. There are samples in C# and (I think) C++ in the SDK folders. You can download the SDK (6.1) and install in VS2008 before you buy.
And all devices I know of let you access the GPS over a COM port as well.

PS: don't forget to look around on MS/download for FakeGPS. A separate install that lets you play recorded GPS in the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

The device should expose itself through the [GPSID driver](http://blogs.msdn.com/croman/archive/2008/08/29/gps-intermediate-driver-one-of-your-best-friends.aspx) (almost all devices from 6.1 on do).  You would then be able to use that API for reading location info.